# Mute just specific person on Skype

Tags: skype

Is it possible to mute just one person during conference call?

I use Skype at work to make everyday teleconference with my team. One of my team members sits in the same room as me, so I don't need to hear her from the speaker. The result is, that I can hear the person twice, with slight delay, speaking "live" in the room and in Skype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question, I believe there is no way to mute just one person. The same problem was already discussed [on Skype support community](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Mute-someone-in-Conference-at-Skype/td-p/35246).

Answer (score 0):

If you are the leader of the conversation you can type the following command in the chat:

```
/setrole [skypename] LISTENER
```

That will make them able to listen, but not talk.

If you then want them normal again you can type:

```
/setrole [skypename] USER
```

You can see all commands by typing `/w` or a slash and any other letter.

Comment: Will that allow other people in the conference to listen to the second person?

Comment: @Luke - Of course not, they would only be able to listen, which is clearly not what the author wanted.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that time you can mute that person. If you don't know [how to mute a person on skype](http://www.internetgeeks.org/social/how-to-mute-someone-on-skype/), then check here.

Comment: -1 as answers should not be link-only.